# Bring swallows nest into the EU

Tags: food-and-drink, eu, regulations, import-taxes

I am arriving from Vietnam to Sweden in about one week. I would like to bring a small quantity of dried swallows nest with me to Sweden. I have read that importing swallows nest into USA is not allowed, but I can not find any explicit mention of swallows nest in regards to the EU (only about meat, dairy, and so on, and swallows nest is neither). Does anyone know the regulations regarding this item?

Comment: What are swallows nest? Here in Europe we may think something different. Note there are restriction on vegetables, wood, and other product which may carry insects and diseases.

Comment: It might not be explicitly mentioned. If you’re referring to nests made from bird saliva, it could be covered under regulations regarding animal/bird *products* in general. Try searching the generic term ‘bird’s nest’. Can you even legally export them from Vietnam?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Swallows nest is basically dried bird saliva

Comment: The [Official Journal of the European Union](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32021R0632&from=EN) covers "animals, products of animal origin, germinal products, animal by-products and derived products, composite products, and hay and straw". These are all regulated.

Comment: Work your way through that! It does mention Salanganes’ nests (“birds nests”).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, that's the pointer I needed (hopefully), I'll add an answer if I find one (and if nobody else does it before I have the time)

Comment: The document isn't easy to read but from what I can tell they are controlled, not banned and must be presented at border control. Section 0410. It defines various products in detail, but not their specific rules.

Answer (score 5):

It is at least for practical purposes, albeit with a small number of exceptions, not possible (at least not realistic) for private persons to import products of animal origin into the EU.

This question is about canned meat, but my answer to that question applies to all kinds of animal products:

[Can I bring a few cans of meat into the EU? If so, how?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179760/can-i-bring-a-few-cans-of-meat-into-the-eu-if-so-how/179781#179781)

Comment: While you're legally correct, for all *practical* purposes there are no checks for animal products when entering the EU.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Of course there are. I have been subject to that myself and you only have to watch any of the many European offshoots of 'Border Security' to see that animal products (usually meat or cheese) is both found and confiscated at the EU border.

Comment: Yes, there are random inspections, but that's very different from a country like Australia where *every* traveller has to go through biosecurity checks and sniffer dogs etc are frequently used.  And since we're trading anecdotes, I've never, not once, had.my bags inspected when arriving in the EU by air; land borders are a different story.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Customs at most airports do random checks of your bags before you pick them up at the conveyor belt. If they don't find anything interesting, you will not notice that you have been inspected. Organic material in your luggage is easily spotted if your luggage is x-rayed.

Comment: @lambshaanxy While you're not outright saying, 'go ahead and bring it', you're implying that it's okay to bring it even though it's against regulations.